# Can I use side buttons of my phone to turn (by holding) next/prev track without root?

Tags: music-player, buttons

I have xperia M. It has normal walkman player. But choosing music is not comfortable, it needs taking out my phone from a pocket. How can I custom side volume buttons to turn next/prev. track by holding it a while? (How it was in old walkman telephones)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible approaches to this.

If you're using a headset (which I assume you are), there are several [apps for headset control](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=83) allowing you to use your headset button for that (e.g. one click = pause/play, double-click = next, etc.).

On the other hand I've seen [C Locker](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.ccs.lockscreen) is capable of exactly what you're asking for: using the volume rockers for that while the screen is locked.

Comment: Thank you. C-Locker is very close, what I want. But I must ask: is there a program without lock screen? It will be perfect)). (sadly I have a earphones without buttons, and can not use programs of first approach(( )

Comment: Our default answer to ~50% of the questions might fit that: [tasker](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tasker) has music control and can play with (some) buttons. Not sure about volume controls, but "there might be an addon for that" ;) (plenty of Tasker addons available).